# How to remove null character (zero character) from string

Tags: vb.net, unicode, character-encoding, ascii, null-character

I been trying to remove all the zero characters from my string

My string is made from these hexadecimal bytes

> 00 44 00 65 00 6C 00 70 00 68 00 69

For every letter there is a Zero byte (null byte) in front of it.. I was guessing I had to use some kind of Unicode encoding or wide encoding to get the text without those zero's.

But I couldn't figure it out so I figured best way is to use a Replace but even that fails.

```
Dim packet() As String = {&H0, &H44, &H0, &H65, &H0, &H6C, &H0, &H70, &H0, &H68, &H0, &H69}
Dim str As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet, 0, 12)
str = str.Replace("\0", "")  'Compiles and fails
str = str.Replace(\0, "")  'No compile
str = str.Replace('\0', "")  'No compile
```

Comment: The reason it fails is that VB does not use/recognize escape characters in strings.  Thats apparently to avoid things like `"C:\\MyTemp\\SomeFile.Ext"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real problem is not the null bytes, but in how you are decoding the bytes Ínto a `String` in the first place.  You are using the wrong `Encoding`. You should be using [`Encoding.BigEndianUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.bigendianunicode.aspx) instead of `Encoding.ASCII`, then you don't need to replace the nulls manually at all as they will be handled for you by the decoding process:

```
Dim packet() As Byte = {&H0, &H44, &H0, &H65, &H0, &H6C, &H0, &H70, &H0, &H68, &H0, &H69}
Dim str As String = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(packet)
```

Comment: Perfect I knew it was unicode but I didn't know why it didn't work. This is the one yup

Comment: @SSpoke In the Microsoft .NET Base Class libraries (and much of Microsoft's work), "Unicode" refers not to just the character set, but (esoterically) to the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set. Remy points out, UTF-16 has a byte order that you need to consider. (For comparison, there are other encodings for Unicode. UTF-8 is very popular, in fact, it's the default for .NET's file streams.)

Comment: In particular, Microsoft uses UTF-16 **Little Endian** everywhere (what `Encoding.Unicode` uses). But some protocols/platforms use **Big Endian** instead, which is why `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` is also offered.

Answer (score 8):

If you want something that doesn't rely on the Microsoft.Visualbasic namespace:

```
str = str.Replace(Convert.ToChar(0),"")
```

The only alternative is to using String.Replace I can think of is to use a regex replace: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Or simply `str = str.Replace(Char.MinValue, "")`

Comment: This is the wrong answer. It is a band-aid that addresses the symptom, not fixes the root cause - the wrong `Encoding` is being used to convert the bytes to a `String`. Fix the encoding and the replacement is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Solved it

```
 str = str.Replace(vbNullChar, "")
```

Still looking for a way to do this with a built-in function not relying on `Replace` function

Comment: What is 'Replace' if it is not "built-in"?

Comment: Replace is built-in Visual Basic.NET edition any String you just type a `.` dot and it shows you a list of possible commands you can use. Yeah in Visual Basic 6 you just use `Replace(str, "Hi", "Bye")` also built-in. OPPS HAHA I miss read my own answer. Yeah I goofed up. Just using functions like `Replace` is like a quick-fix in my opinion and not a solid fix. It's like relying on `Replace` when you  need to use Regular Expressions. Or using Regular Expressions when you need to build a full-fletched HTML Parser.